# How do I tell Maxima about valid approximations of subexpressions of a large expression?

Tags: maxima

I have a fairly large expression that involves a lot of subexpressions of the form `(100*A^3 + 200*A^2 + 100*A)*x` or `(-A^2 - A)*y` or `(100*A^2 + 100*A)*z`

*I* know, but I don't know how to tell Maxima this, that it in this case is  valid to make the approximation `A+1 ~ A`, thereby effectively removing anything but the highest power of `A` in each coefficient.

I'm now looking for functions, tools, or methods that I can use to guide Maxima in dropping various terms that aren't important.

I have attempted with `subst`, but that requires me to specify each and every factor separately, because:

```
subst([A+1=B], (A+2)*(A+1)*2);
subst([A+1=B], (A+2)*(A*2+2));
(%o1) 2*(A+2)*B
(%o2) (A+2)*(2*A+2)
```

(that is, I need to add one expression for each slightly different variant)

I tried with `ratsimp`, but that's too eager to change every occurrence:

```
ratsubst(B, A+1, A*(A+1)*2);
ratsubst(B, A+1, A*(A*2+2));
(%o3) 2*B^2-2*B
(%o4) 2*B^2-2*B
```

which isn't actually simpler, as I would have preferred the answer to have been given as `2*B^2`.

In another answer, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22695050/5999883) the functions `let` and `letsimp` were suggested for the task of substituting values, but I fail to get them to really do anything:

```
x:(A+1)*A;
let ( A+1, B );
letsimp(x);
(x)A*(A+1)
(%o6) A+1 --\> B
(%o7) A^2+A
```

Again, I'd like to approximate this expression to `A^2` (`B^2`, whatever it's called).

I understand that this is, in general, a hard problem (is e.g. `A^2 + 10^8*A` still okay to approximate as `A^2`?) but I think that what I'm looking for is a function or method of calculation that would be a little bit smarter than `subst` and can recognize that the same substitution could be done in the expression `A^2+A` as in the expression `100*A^2+100*A` or `-A^2-A` instead of making me create a list of three (or twenty) individual substitutions when calling `subst`. The "nice" part of the full expression that I'm working on is that each of these `A` factors are of the form `k*A^n*(A+1)^m` for various small integers `n`, `m`, so I never actually end up with the degenerate case mentioned above.

(I was briefly thinking of re-expressing my expression as a polynomial in `A`, but this will not work as the only valid approximation of the expression `(A^3+A^2+A)*x + y` is `A^3*x + y` -- I know nothing about the relative sizes of `x` and `y`.

Comment: A problem like this probably requires some discussion. My advice is to post a message to the maxima-discuss list. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss