# Simplification with letsimp in Maxima, what is going on?

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima, wxmaxima

Here is a simple session with maxima, in which im trying to make the simplification **(r-r0)=h**

```
(%i1) ax: G*M*m*(r-r0)/r0^2 - G*M*m/r0 ;
                            G M m (r - r0)   G M m
(%o1)                       -------------- - -----
                                   2          r0
                                 r0
(%i2) let(r-r0,h);
(%o2)                            r - r0 --> h
(%i3) expand(scanmap(letsimp,ax));
                               G M m r   2 G M m
(%o3)                          ------- - -------
                                   2       r0
                                 r0
```

I was expecting this in the last part:

```
                               G M m h   2 G M m
                              ------- - -------
                                   2       r0
                                 r0
```

Why did maxima replace *(r-r0)* with  *r* rather than with *h*?
Iv attempted letsimp and letrat as instructed in this other question: [common subexpressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685853/maxima-how-to-replace-common-subexpressions-with-symbols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r - r0` is not a form supported by `let`. From the documentation:

> -- Function: let
>             let (, , , , ..., )
>             let ([, , , , ..., ],
>             )
>
> ```
>  Defines a substitution rule for 'letsimp' such that <prod> is
>  replaced by <repl>.  <prod> is a product of positive or negative
>  powers of the following terms:
>
>     * Atoms which 'letsimp' will search for literally unless
>       previous to calling 'letsimp' the 'matchdeclare' function is
>       used to associate a predicate with the atom.  In this case
>       'letsimp' will match the atom to any term of a product
>       satisfying the predicate.
>     * Kernels such as 'sin(x)', 'n!', 'f(x,y)', etc.  As with atoms
>       above 'letsimp' will look for a literal match unless
>       'matchdeclare' is used to associate a predicate with the
>       argument of the kernel.
> ```

In this case one can start with a syntactic substitution:

```
    (%i1) ax: G*M*m*(r-r0)/r0^2 - G*M*m/r0 $

    (%i2) subst(h, r - r0, ax);
                                    G M h m   G M m
    (%o2)                           ------- - -----
                                        2      r0
                                      r0
```